# I can only press one button and call one function at a time. then I need to close to re-run another function

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

```
import tkinter //tkinter
import time
import serial
from tkinter import ttk
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
import sys 
import numpy as np

ac = Gps = irS = PM = x = Sid = fplN = initFlag = flightplanFlag = 0 


"""MCDU WINDOW"""

#MCDU frame
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.attributes("-zoomed", True)
window.title("MCDU")

#frame dimensions
Topframe = tkinter.Frame(window, width = 1185, height = 560, bg = "cyan")
Topframe.place(x = 0, y = 0)
#bottomFrame = tkinter.Frame(window, width = 640, height = 840, bg = "red")
#bottomFrame.place(x = 940, y = 0)


ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600) // arduino
ArduinoSerial.flush()

"""MCDU DISPLAY SCREEN"""

#black screen
def screen():
  topFrame = tkinter.Frame(window, width = 720, height = 560, bg = "black")
  topFrame.place(x = 465, y =0) 
  entry = tkinter.Entry(window, fg = "white", bg = "black")
  entry.place(x = 485, y = 540) 
     
       

#MCDU menu screen //screen
def MCDUmenu():
    screen()
    menuTitle = tkinter.Label(window, text = "MCDU MENU", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 16, "bold"), 
    bg = "black")
    menuTitle.place(x = 750, y = 25)
    fmgc = tkinter.Label(window, text = "<FMGC", fg = "green", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), bg = 
    "black")
    fmgc.place(x = 510, y = 77)
    atsu = tkinter.Label(window, text = "<ATSU", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    atsu.place(x = 510, y = 156)
    acms = tkinter.Label(window, text = "<ACMS", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    acms.place(x = 510, y = 235)
    sat = tkinter.Label(window, text = "<SAT", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    sat.place(x = 510, y = 393)
    Return = tkinter.Label(window, text = "RETURN >", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), bg 
= "black")
    Return.place(x = 1040, y = 468)

#data index page
def DataIndex():
    screen() 
    dataTitle = tkinter.Label(window, text = "DATA INDEX", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 16, 
"bold"), bg = "black")
    dataTitle.place(x = 650, y = 25)
    position = tkinter.Label(window, text = """   POSITION
< MONITOR""", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), bg = "black")
    position.place(x = 510, y = 60)
    irs = tkinter.Label(window, text = "IRS", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 12, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    irs.place(x = 527, y = 130)
    Imonitor = tkinter.Label(window, text = "< MONITOR", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), 
bg = "black")
    Imonitor.place(x = 510, y = 156)
    gps = tkinter.Label(window, text = "GPS", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 12, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    gps.place(x = 527, y = 209)
    Gmonitor = tkinter.Label(window, text = "< MONITOR", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), 
bg = "black")
    Gmonitor.place(x = 510, y = 235)
    ACstatus = tkinter.Label(window, text = "< A/C STATUS", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, 
"bold"), bg = "black")
ACstatus.place(x = 510, y = 300)
    page1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "1/2    ← →", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 16, "bold"), bg 
= "black")
    page1.place(x = 950, y = 25)
    d1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "PRINT", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 11, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    d1.place(x = 1080, y = 367)
    d2 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "FUNCTION>", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    d2.place(x = 1030, y = 393)
    d3 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "AOC", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 11, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    d3.place(x = 1093, y = 442)
    d4 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "FUNCTION>", fg = "white", font = ("arial", 14, "bold"), bg = 
"black")
    d4.place(x = 1030, y = 468)



def var():
        var = ArduinoSerial.read() //read from arduino
        print(var)
    if b'm' == var 
        print(var)
        MCDUmenu()
      
    elif b'd' == var:
        print(var)
        DataIndex()
    

    
var()        
window.mainloop()
```

i cant keep pressing my buttons to call out different functions. for example i press Menu Button. it runs but i need to close the program and re-run my codes to press another function like DATA button.Ive tried alot of things but still cannot.

Comment: Well, you only call `var()` once, giving the user only one chance to make a selection.  You would need to call it repeatedly (using `.after()`, and with a timeout on the serial read so it doesn't lock up the program).

Comment: so i just need to add .after() after the var() ?